# how can i use pivot for more columns.?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i have a table LEAVTYPE:-

```
      LM_ID EMPCODE CCODE   FINYEAR  LVTYPE WEF                 OPN_BAL ENTITLE ELIGIBLE    AVAILED
       1    180480  IBTEH   2015-2016   CL  2015-07-31 00:00:00 4.50    0   4.50    1.50
       3    180480  IBTEH   2015-2016   LE  2015-07-31 00:00:00 35.50   0   35.50   0.00
       4    180480  IBTEH   2015-2016   PL  2015-07-31 00:00:00 6.00    1   7.00    0.00
       8    180541  IBTEH   2015-2016   LE  2015-07-31 00:00:00 33.50   0   33.50   0.50
       9    180541  IBTEH   2015-2016   PL  2015-07-31 00:00:00 1.50    1   2.50    1.50
      11    180546  IBTEH   2015-2016   CL  2015-07-31 00:00:00 8.00    0   8.00    1.00
      13    180546  IBTEH   2015-2016   LE  2015-07-31 00:00:00 32.00   0   32.00   0.00
      14    180546  IBTEH   2015-2016   PL  2015-07-31 00:00:00 6.00    1   7.00    0.00
      15    180546  IBTEH   2015-2016   CO  2015-07-31 00:00:00 1.00    0   1.00    1.00
```

now i want to table structure like:-

```
LM_ID  EMPCODE CCODE  FINYEAR     WEF                CL_OPN_BAL     CL_ENTITLE     CL_ELIGIBLE   CL_AVAILED    LE_OPN_BAL     LE_ENTITLE     LE_ELIGIBLE   LE_AVAILED    PL_OPN_BAL     PL_ENTITLE     PL_ELIGIBLE   PL_AVAILED 

1      180480  IBTEH 2015-2016  2015-07-31 00:00:00  4.50            0              4.50          1.50          35.50          0              35.50          0.00          6.00           1            7.00             0.00
```

how can i get this for each group of EMPCOPDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of you can make use of `CROSS APPLY` or `OUTER APPLY` to get columns to rows so as to combine row values with column names

```
SELECT DISTINCT LM_ID,EMPCODE, CCODE, FINYEAR, WEF,
LVTYPE+'_'+COLNAME COLNAME,VALS
INTO NEWTBL
FROM TEMPTBL 
OUTER APPLY(VALUES (OPN_BAL,'OPN_BAL'),(ENTITLE,'ENTITLE'),(ELIGIBLE,'ELIGIBLE'),(AVAILED,'AVAILED'))
COLUMNNAMES(VALS,COLNAME)
```

Now I have inserted this to a temporary table `NEWTBL` so as to reuse for selecting columns to `PIVOT` as well as an easy readability in dynamic `PIVOT`.

Here I declare a variable to select column names for pivoting.

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + COLNAME + ']', '[' + COLNAME + ']')
               FROM (SELECT DISTINCT COLNAME FROM NEWTBL) PV 
               ORDER BY COLNAME
```

Now you should execute it in dynamic query as the columns names are dynamic in nature.

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM 
             (
                 SELECT DISTINCT LM_ID,EMPCODE, CCODE, FINYEAR, WEF, COLNAME, VALS 
                 FROM NEWTBL
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                 MIN(VALS)
                 FOR COLNAME IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) p
            '     
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

Below is the working version

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/301bd/26)**

**EDIT :**

Why my above answer is getting repeated `EMPCODE` is that I have added `LM_ID` as per your expected result. In such case, it will group according to that also. Just don't include `LM_ID` in your result, you will get unique row for each `EMPCODE`.

**[Click here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/352848)** to view result

Comment: U can also use Hash table instead of permanent tables. Please respond if u have any doubt @david sam

Comment: I want all data of a EMPCODE in a single row but your query gives a EMPCODE in many rows

Comment: U could have added more number of rows in ur expected result. K. I will update @david sam

Comment: I have updated. See the edit part and check the result by clicking **Click here** link. If it doesn't run automatically, just run the button **Run Query** @david sam

Answer (score 1):

This will work. We will collect other stats from groups on the basis of LVTYPE.

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT LM_ID, EMPCODE, CCODE, FINYEAR, WEF, 
        CASE WHEN LVTYPE ='CL' THEN (OPN_BAL) END AS CL_OPN_BAL, 
        CASE WHEN LVTYPE ='CL' THEN (ENTITLE) END AS CL_ENTITLE, 
        CASE WHEN LVTYPE ='CL' THEN (ELIGIBLE) END AS CL_ELIGIBLE,
        CASE WHEN LVTYPE ='CL' THEN (AVAILED) END AS CL_AVAILED ,
        CASE WHEN LVTYPE ='LE' THEN (OPN_BAL) END AS LE_OPN_BAL,
        CASE WHEN LVTYPE ='LE' THEN (ENTITLE) END AS LE_ENTITLE,
        CASE WHEN LVTYPE ='LE' THEN (ELIGIBLE) END AS LE_ELIGIBLE,
        CASE WHEN LVTYPE ='LE' THEN (AVAILED) END AS LE_AVAILED, 
        CASE WHEN LVTYPE ='PL' THEN (OPN_BAL) END AS PL_OPN_BAL, 
        CASE WHEN LVTYPE ='PL' THEN (ENTITLE) END AS PL_ENTITLE, 
        CASE WHEN LVTYPE ='PL' THEN (ELIGIBLE) END AS PL_ELIGIBLE,
        CASE WHEN LVTYPE ='PL' THEN (AVAILED) END AS PL_AVAILED,             
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EMPCOPDE ORDER BY EMPCOPDE) as indx
    FROM  LEAVTYPE

)

SELECT LM_ID, EMPCODE, CCODE, FINYEAR, WEF, CL_OPN_BAL, CL_ENTITLE, CL_ELIGIBLE,CL_AVAILED ,LE_OPN_BAL,LE_ENTITLE, LE_ELIGIBLE, LE_AVAILED, PL_OPN_BAL, PL_ENTITLE, PL_ELIGIBLE, PL_AVAILED
FROM CTE 
WHERE indx=1
```

There will be many records in a group with different indx values. Here index=1 will show one record from each group.

Comment: @davidsam would you like to show me results of this query? With a screen shot. Or send table structure.

Comment: Then remove the  'WHERE indx=1' condition and check the results. update me.

Comment: after removing where condition it gives one EMPCODE many times and also gives null values